# Cassandra comments data model

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to store very simple comments in a wide row, but the problem is that i want to have top comments.

So at first I have tried to use `UTF8` comparator type and each column name would begin by likes amount and would be followed by timestamp, for example:

```
Comments_CF = {
    parent:{
        8_timestamp: comment,
        5_timestamp: comment,
        1_timestamp: comment,
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem with this approach is that for example `2_timestamp` > `19_timestamp` because lexicographically `2` is bigger than `19`

I could probably store top comments in a separate CF but then i would need to do two queries instead of one so i would really like to avoid that, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 queries instead of one is usually not a big deal.  You could also just do a composite value(number of likes+the comment) and sort the comments yourself....From stuff I have seen there is never alot of comments except a few posts anyways so that would be very quick.

There are other patterns that might spark ideas here as well...

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/wiki/Patterns-Page

Comment: In reality i already have in some cases from 2 to 4 other queries done to load some other stuff, so i would like to avoid anything that i don't need. I will definitely look at composite values, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a composite, where the first component is a long and the second is whatever type is appropriate for your timestamp format.  This way the sorting will be correct.